# How does static factory method infer generics?

Tags: java, lombok

Going through this doc: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

I came across the following:
"the generated constructor is always private, and an additional static factory method that wraps around the private constructor is generated. [...] Such a static factory method will infer generics, unlike a normal constructor. This means your API users get write `MapEntry.of("foo", 5)` instead of the much longer `new MapEntry<String, Integer>("foo", 5)`"

Can someone explain to me the mechanics for why this is the case?

Comment: I would point out that since Java 7 (what was that, 2011?) you wouldn't write the "much longer" form either: you'd use the diamond operator.